# How to make sure that it is only one http:// in a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I make sure that it is only one **http://** in a string?

```
$url = "http://mysite.com/http://http://mysite.com/";

# set the regex for checking.
$regex = '/^\bhttp:\b\/\/.*/';

# reject the url address if it doesn't match
if (!preg_match($regex, $url)) echo 'false';
```

Comment: It is valid URL, why would you want to filter it?

Comment: @nhahtdh For reasons other than validity, apparently.

Comment: I hope that he doesn't use this to filter "bad" URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`strrpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php):

```
if (strrpos($url, "http://") > 0) {
   // reject
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is extremely useful to consult [the manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).
It contains way better solutions than you can find on Stackoverflow from a mere passer-by.

Yet is is not that hard to browse a few dozen functions briefly, just to make yourself a picture.

You can easily find a *robust* [answer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to the question from the title

```
if (substr_count($url,"http://") > 1)
```

which will work with any position of the needle, not only at the beginning.

There are also other ways including [strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with offset and many more.